# Running LXC and Docker on the same host

Tags: docker, lxc

I'm running a private server for a some time now and back when I set it up, I used LXC to separate the different services from each other.

About a month ago I've started to use docker (for work as well as privately) and from now on I'd like to use it for new services (and slowly migrate the old ones to it).

So long story short: Is it possible to run both LXC and Docker on the same host for as long as it takes me to migrate one service after the other?

The server is running Debian Jessie 64bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing that prevents this since docker libcontainer is basically a superset of LXC. Simply make sure IP ranges don't overlap between the two (or more) bridges.